# Checkboxes on page loaded with XMLhttpRequest

Tags: php, javascript, html, checkbox, xmlhttprequest

On my main page I have a select with option for ticket status, and a submit button and a textarea. I have a list of tickets with a checkbox for each tickets, and on the list is displayed various informations about the tickets.

Like so:

```
 _________________________________ \
|checkbox|ticket name|user|status| |
|checkbox|ticket name|user|status| |
|checkbox|ticket name|user|status| |
|checkbox|ticket name|user|status| |--> this is on my list.php page
|checkbox|ticket name|user|status| |
|checkbox|ticket name|user|status| |
|________________________________| |
 ___________________________       /
|select status|submit button| \
|___________________________| |
 ___________________________  |--> this is on my main page
|         text area         | |
|___________________________| /
```

The list of tickets is loaded using "list.php" via an XMLhttpRequest. When I input text, then select a status, check the tickets I want to update and press submit it will send the information via a POST XMLhttpRequest and refresh the page.

My XMLhttpRequest sends the textarea, the status and the submit from my main page to list.php. The problem is the checkboxes - since they are on the page list.php, I don't know how to deal with them.

I check them before the refresh and when I press submit since it refreshes list.php with the new data sent with post the checkboxes reset and I can't get the one that are checked. I want the checkboxes to be reset but only after my request is done.

Any ideas?

I posted a simplified example of my two pages on Pastebin here:

- http://pastebin.com/dy9k3u8T > main.php
- http://pastebin.com/icxgbham > list.php

Comment: It isn't entirely clear (to me at least) what the problem is. If you can write shorter sentences, with clearer descriptions, that might help. It seems that you are loading in the HTML for various tick boxes via an AJAX request, which are displaying correctly. Then, you send the contents of the form via another AJAX request, once the form has been completed. The problem is in the second thing. Is that correct?

Comment: My problem is, when I check the tickets I want to update and I click on submit the checkboxes reset before the request is done. Because the request is done after the refresh of list.php and the checkboxes are on this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can do everything you need with JavaScript & jQuery

NOTE: THIS CODE IS UN-TESTED, IT WILL POINT YOU IN THE RIGHT DIRECTION BUT IT MAY HAVE SYNTAX ERRORS OR NOT MATCH UP WITH YOUR CODE.

**First, swap your AJAX calls over to jQuery POST method**

You've already included jQuery in your simplified page, so don't use those roundabout XMLHttpRequests when you can use simple jQuery to do a `POST` request (typically you'd do this on less lines but I've spaced it out so it's easier to read):

```
function reloadList(statuses) {
    $.post(
        'list.php',
        {
           'data': some-variable,
           'more-data': some-other-variable 
        },
        function(data,status) {
           $('#list').html(data);
           restoreCheckedStatus(statuses);
        }
    );
}
```

You will need to fill in the POST data.

**Next, we need a function to save the status of those checkboxes**

Using jQuery selectors, we're going to iterate over every checkbox on the page and store whether it's checked or not in an array:

```
function saveCheckedStatus() {
    var statuses = new Array();
    $(':checkbox').each(function(){
        // Store the checkbox ID and checked status in an array
        var cbox = new Array();
        var cbox['id'] = $(this).attr('id');
        var cbox['checked'] = $(this).is(':checked');
        statuses.push(cbox);
    });
    return statuses;
}
```

**We also need a function to restore those statuses**

After this, we'll make a function to restore these statuses from an input array:

```
function restoreCheckedStatus(statuses) {
    for(var cbox in statuses) {
        // Set a checkbox checked or unchecked based on ID
        $('#'+cbox['id']).attr('checked', cbox['checked']);
    }
}
```

**Finally, throw it all together**

Now, we need to wait for someone to click on the Submit button, then do all of the above in the right order:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var statuses = saveCheckedStatus();
    reloadList(statuses);
});
```

This should solve your problems. If you get it working based on this syntax, please let me know anything that's wrong so that I can edit my answer to be useful in future.